# How do I save base64-encoded image data to a file in a dynamically named subfolder

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, base64, jpeg

I have a table containing base64-encoded jpegs as well as some other data. The base64 string is stored in a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column.

How can I save these images out to actual files inside folders that are dynamically named using other data from the table in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by combining a lot of small tips from different places and wanted to collate them all here as no one seemed to have the full process.

I have two tables, called `Photos` and `PhotoBinary`. `Photos` contains at least a `PhotoID BIGINT`, the `Base64` data `VARCHAR(MAX)`, and something to get the `FolderName` from - `NVARCHAR(15)` - increase as needed. I also have a `BIT` field to mark them as `isProcessed`. `PhotoBinary` has a single `VARBINARY(MAX)`  column and should be empty.

The second table serves two purposes, it holds the converted base64 encoded image in binary format, and allows me to work around the fact that BCP will not let you skip columns when exporting data from a table when using a "format file" to specify the column formats. So in my case the data has to sit in a table all on its own, I did try taking it from a view but had the aforementioned issue with not being allowed to skip the id column.

The main stored procedure has a `bcp` command that depends upon an `.fmt` file created using the following SQL. I'm pretty sure I had to edit the resulting file with a plain text editor to change the `8` to a `0` that indicates the prefix length after `SQLBINARY`. I couldn't just use the `-n` switch on the command in the main stored procedure as it resulted in an 8 byte prefix being put into the resulting file, which made it an invalid jpeg. So, I used the edited format file to get around that.

```sql
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(4000);
SET @command = 'bcp DB.dbo.PhotoBinary format nul -T -n -f "A:\pathto\photobinary.fmt"';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @command;
```

I then have the following in a stored procedure that I run to export the images into an appropriate folder:

```sql
DECLARE  @command       VARCHAR(4000),
         @photoId       BIGINT,
         @imageFileName VARCHAR(128),
         @folderName    NVARCHAR(15),
         @basePath      NVARCHAR(500),
         @fullPath      NVARCHAR(500),
         @dbServerName  NVARCHAR(100);

DECLARE @directories TABLE (directory nvarchar(255), depth INT);

-- The location of the output folder
SET @basePath = '\\server\share';
-- The server that the photobinary db is on
SET @dbServerName = 'localhost';

-- @basePath values, get the folders already in the output folder
INSERT INTO @directories(directory, depth) EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @basePath;

-- Cursor for each image in table that hasn't already been exported
DECLARE photo_cursor CURSOR  FOR
    SELECT PhotoID,
           'some_image_' + CAST(PhotoID AS NVARCHAR) + '.jpg',
           FolderName
    FROM   dbo.Photos
    WHERE  isProcessed = 0;

OPEN photo_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM photo_cursor
    INTO @photoId,
         @imageFileName,
         @folderName;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) -- Cursor loop 
BEGIN
    -- Create the @basePath directory
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @directories WHERE directory = @folderName)
    BEGIN
        SET @fullPath = @basePath + '\' + @folderName;
        EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @fullPath;
    END


    -- move and convert the base64 encoded image to a separate table in binary format
    -- it should be the only row in the table
    INSERT INTO DB.dbo.PhotoBinary (PhotoBinary)
        SELECT CAST(N'' AS xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("Base64"))', 'varbinary(max)')
            FROM DB.dbo.Photos
            WHERE PhotoID = @photoId;

    -- This command uses the command-line BCP tool to "bulk export" the image data in binary to an "archive" file that just happens to be a jpg
    SET @command = 'bcp "SELECT TOP 1 PhotoBinary FROM DB.dbo.PhotoBinary" queryout "' + @basePath + '\' + @folderName + '\' + @imageFileName + '" -T -S ' + @dbServerName + ' -f "A:\pathto\photobinary.fmt"';
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @command;

    -- clean up the photo data
    DELETE FROM DB.dbo.PhotoBinary;

    -- mark photo as processed
    UPDATE DB.dbo.Photos SET isProcessed = 1 WHERE PhotoID = @photoId;

    FETCH NEXT FROM photo_cursor
        INTO @photoId,
             @imageFileName,
             @folderName;
  END  -- cursor loop

CLOSE photo_cursor

DEALLOCATE photo_cursor
```